# IEnumerable with multiple data members

Tags: c#, ienumerable

How to implement iteration trought many types of data members?

This is interface which I must have implemented

```
interface ISeries : IReadOnlyList<Tuple<DateTime, double>>
{
    IEnumerable<DateTime> Time { get; }
    IEnumerable<double> Values { get; }
}
```

Class of my custom object with DateTime and double in it

```
class TimeEvent
{
    public DateTime Time;
    public double Value;
    public TimeEvent(DateTime time, double value)
    {
        Time = time;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Class of my custom series made of TimeEvents

```
class TimeSeries : ISeries
{
    List<TimeEvent> TimeEvents;

    public TimeSeries(List<TimeEvent> timeEvents)
    {
        TimeEvents = timeEvents;
    }

    public Tuple<DateTime, double> this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return new Tuple<DateTime, double>(TimeEvents[index].Time, TimeEvents[index].Value);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeEvents.Count;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Time
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<double> Values
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Tuple<DateTime, double>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return TimeEvents.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And here is basicaly what I am trying to use it for. So I can iterate trought items in TimeSeries. Much like in dictionary.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TimeEvent t1 = new TimeEvent(new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), 64);
        TimeEvent t2 = new TimeEvent(new DateTime(2017, 2, 3), 128);
        TimeEvent t3 = new TimeEvent(new DateTime(2017, 3, 6), 256);
        List<TimeEvent> list = new List<TimeEvent>();
        list.Add(t1);
        list.Add(t2);
        list.Add(t3);
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(list);

        foreach(DateTime date in series.Time)
            Console.WriteLine(date);

        foreach (double d in series.Values)
            Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
List<TimeEvent> TimeEvents;

public TimeSeries(List<TimeEvent> timeEvents)
{
    TimeEvents = timeEvents;
}

public IEnumerable<DateTime> Time
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var item in TimeEvents)
        {
            yield return item.Time;
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<double> Values
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var item in TimeEvents)
        {
            yield return item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just

public IEnumerable<DateTime> Time => TimeEvents.Select(x => x.Time); and

public IEnumerable<double> Values => TimeEvents.Select(x => x.Value);

Comment: ckuri yes that is even better, thnx

Answer (score 1):

Would something simpler work for you?

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), 64d));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2017, 2, 3), 128d));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2017, 3, 6), 256d));

foreach (Tuple<DateTime, double> tuple in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime={0:yyyy/dd/mm}, Double={1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
}
```

Seems [working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hHxrVh).

Comment: Tuple is good for this, I would use it but I have to implement that interface. Anyway thnx. I also have more members so it would be chaotic.